# Read text file and over write with changes

Tags: c#, openfiledialog

I want read and write in the same time, in a text File. How can I do that? I searched on Internet, but I don't really understand much. In this action, I want to use the tool OpenFileDialog.
This is the code:

```
private void controlla_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Regex rgx = new Regex(@"\d");

    if (string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(text_scrivi.Text) || rgx.IsMatch(text_scrivi.Text))
        MessageBox.Show("Errore. Bisogna inserire una parola");
    else
    {
        string line;
        string sen_text = text_scrivi.Text.Trim();
        //MessageBox.Show(sen_text);
        bool esito = true;
        StreamReader file = new StreamReader(@"%USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Ghilardi\Parole\280000_parole_italiane");
        while ((line = file.ReadLine()) != null && (esito))
        {
            if (string.Compare(line, sen_text) == 0)
            {
                MessageBox.Show("La Parole e' presente nel vocabolario");
                esito = false;
            }

        }
        file.Close();
        if (esito)
        {
            DialogResult scelta = MessageBox.Show("La Parole non è presente nel vocabolario", "Salvare Nuova Parola", MessageBoxButtons.YesNoCancel, MessageBoxIcon.Question);
            if (scelta == DialogResult.No)
                text_scrivi.Text = "";
            else
                **if (scelta == DialogResult.Yes)
                {

                 \\I Want open file, read one line at time, and write in a determined position. I don't know, how open file in read and write modal.    

                }**
                else
                    text_scrivi.Text = "";
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you post some code? Your question is unclear. There are many ways to perform file IO in C#.

Comment: Exactly how do you want to read and write at the same time? You need to be specific.

Comment: Writing to a file while you're reading to it is generally a bad idea.  It's *possible*, strictly speaking, but I'd *strongly* advise avoiding doing so if you aren't sure that you have to.

Comment: Reading/writing to the same file is possible, but a better suggestion imo would be to read the file line by line with `StreamReader`, save your changes to a buffer, then call `File.WriteAllText`. Be sure to have StreamReader in a using statement to dispose of the stream afterwards and have File.WriteAllText outside the using so you will avoid any exceptions with opening a file that is already in a stream.

Comment: The question is in the code. And that is position, where i want open file.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest way to read an write from files is to use `File.ReadAllText` and `File.WriteAllText` however you would not be reading an writing at the same time. Also, these methods do not stream the file (it's loaded into memory all at once) so they will likely cause `OutOfMemoryExceptions` if you're working with large files in which case the best route (imo) is to use `StreamReader` and `StreamWriter`

Here's an example;

```
string file = File.ReadAllText(@".\path\to\file.txt");
file = file + "Some string I'm adding to my file";
File.WriteAllText(@".\path\to\file.txt", file); // note this overwrites the file
```

If you need to go the `StreamReader`/`StreamWriter` route i would recommend just looking at the examples on MSDN.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.streamreader(v=vs.110).aspx

EDIT: From what the OP has said in comments I think `ReadAllLines` is a better choice, here is an example;

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@".\path\to\file.txt");

foreach (int i = 0; i < lines.Length; i++)
{
      string forUser = lines[i];
      // show user the line and let them edit it;
      // somethign like forUser = myTextBoxOrWhatever.Text;
      // do validation if yo uwant
      lines[i] = forUser; // this updates your version of the file with the users changes
      // update display if need be
}

File.WriteAllLines(@".\path\to\file.txt", lines);
// this will overwrite the file with the new version
```

Note, when the user is "editing the file" they are not editing the file directly. You have a copy of hte file in memory (RAM) and the user is editing that. After the user is finished you overwrite the entire file with the version in memory. There is no reason to read and write at the same time in order to accomplish this task.

If the file is too big to use `ReadAllLines` the problem becomes more complicated. The way to do that is to read it line by line with `StreamReader`, write the output to a temp file line by line with `StreamWriter` then after you're all done, delete the original file and change the name of the temp file.

Comment: As your answer itself states, you are not writing to the file while you are reading from it.  You are specifically stating that you're not answering the question.  Thus, you aren't answering the question...

Comment: @Servy omg you're just a pain in tha ass servy... Obviously the OP doesn't want to write and read a file at the same time, he just doesn't know how to state his question. Seriously, have you never helped a beginning programmer in your life?

Comment: If he doesn't know how to state his question properly then *help him state his question properly*.  Otherwise someone who needs to read and write to a file at the same time will find this question through Google and get an answer that doesn't help them at all.

Comment: @evanmcdonnal I think you must show respect to colleagues.

Comment: @Servy alright, my apologies. I actually agree with your point about searching and will edit the question's title accordingly. If you didn't notice the OP updated and it is now obvious he doesn't want to read/write at the same time. He wants to load the file into memory, let the user edit it, then write it afterwards.

Comment: I expressed badly. How can i do?Some answer?

Comment: @evanmcdonnal Honestly, the question is entirely too unclear to answer.  It looks like he's trying to edit just a portion of a file in place, but it's not really clear what he wants to change or how.  This may involve reading the whole file in, or it may not; without understandable requirements, you can't really say.  Regardless, providing an answer that's largely unrelated to what the question is asking, and then just editing the question into what you answered without regard for what the author is asking for, isn't appropriate.

Comment: @Servy I don't agree with you there at all, it's easy to read his code and make some assumptions about what he's trying to do. Either way I don't care, just gonna vote to close and forget about it.

Comment: I Want open file (in write and read modal), read one line at time, put a condition (if) where if condition is true, I write in the file, while it is false i continue  the cycle.  Ok, this is what i want do. I don't know, how can i do to open file in read and write modal?

Comment: @user3266682 ok, I'll edit with a suggestion for how to read and write the file. However, you DO NOT WANT TO WRITE THE FILE WHILE YOU'RE READING IT. What you want to do is read the file into memory, edit the copy in memory (not the file itself), then over write the file with the updated version (the version in memory).

Comment: Ok. This is that i will do. Please, one suggest.